Why is there an empty file named google in my /opt folder and is it safe to delete?
I was installing some software and found an empty file titled "google" in my /opt folder. I used the command rmdir to get rid of it. When I later reset my computer all sorts of output I've never seen before printed to the screen before Fedora booted up.
I don't have any google software on my computer and am unsure why it was there.
I'm using Fedora 39.

are you saying that you deleted the /opt directory?

One usually use "rm" to delete files, while "rmdir" is for removing directories. What was the software you installed and what is the "all sort of output " that you refer to?

It was an empty file google, or an empty directory google/ ?

It's not a file, it's a directory and yes, if rmdir takes care of it, it's generally safe. It's a leftover of some Google application that you had installed, probably Google Chrome.

Or google earth...
